# Pull HTML cell data into Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, htmlelements

I'm trying to fetch a single cell from td tags (`<td><font class="s1">52.84</font>`) below using VBA and post it on Excel sheet.

See the HTML snipped below:

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#999999">
                <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="0" width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr bgcolor="#cccccc" align="right" height="20">
                            <td><font class="s1">Price</font></td>
                            <td><font class="s1">Change&nbsp;(%)</font><img src="/design/images/0.gif" width="4" height="1" border="0/"></td>
                            <td><font class="s1">52&nbsp;wk&nbsp;High</font><img src="/design/images/0.gif" width="4" height="1" border="0/"></td>
                            <td><font class="s1">52&nbsp;wk&nbsp;Low</font><img src="/design/images/0.gif" width="4" height="1" border="0/"></td>
                            <td><font class="s1">Stock volume </font><a href="javascript:openHelp(14)" alt="Open Help"><img src="/design/images/ico/q_zn.gif" width="8" height="10" border="0" alt="Open Help"></a><img src="/design/images/0.gif" width="4" height="1" border="0/"></td>
                            <td><font class="s1">1WK Avg Opt Volume</font><a href="javascript:openHelp('avg_1wk_ov')" alt="Open Help"><img src="/design/images/ico/q_zn.gif" width="8" height="10" border="0" alt="Open Help"></a><img src="/design/images/0.gif" width="3" height="1" border="0/"></td>
                            <td><font class="s1">1WK Avg Opt OI</font><a href="javascript:openHelp('avg_1wk_oi')" alt="Open Help"><img src="/design/images/ico/q_zn.gif" width="8" height="10" border="0" alt="Open Help"></a><img src="/design/images/0.gif" width="3" height="1" border="0/"></td>
                            <td><font class="s1">EOD Opt Volume</font><a href="javascript:openHelp('eod_ov')" alt="Open Help"><img src="/design/images/ico/q_zn.gif" width="8" height="10" border="0" alt="Open Help"></a><img src="/design/images/0.gif" width="3" height="1" border="0/"></td>
                            <td><font class="s1">EOD Opt OI</font><a href="javascript:openHelp('eod_oi')" alt="Open Help"><img src="/design/images/ico/q_zn.gif" width="8" height="10" border="0" alt="Open Help"></a><img src="/design/images/0.gif" width="3" height="1" border="0/"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="right" height="20"> ***
                            <td><font class="s1">52.84</font>*** </td>
                            <td><font class="s1"><nobr>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="/design/images/ico/arrow_bottom.gif" alt="-" border="0" align="absmiddle" width="7" height="9/">&nbsp;-1.06&nbsp;(-1.97%)</nobr></font></td>
                            <td><font class="s1"><nobr>&nbsp;&nbsp;60.34&nbsp;07/22/2015</nobr></font></td>
                            <td><font class="s1"><nobr>&nbsp;&nbsp;46.95&nbsp;01/30/2015</nobr></font></td>
                            <td><font size="-2" class="s1">17,092,380</font></td>
                            <td><font size="-2" class="s1">87,610</font></td>
                            <td><font size="-2" class="s1">1,820,400</font></td>
                            <td><font size="-2" class="s1">54,450</font></td>
                            <td><font size="-2" class="s1">1,858,857</font></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Okay.  Have you [tried anything](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: Use the "code" button `{}` to format your HTML - and add *line breaks*

Comment: Source example http://www.ivolatility.com/options.j?period=12&chart=2&ticker=WYNN%3ANASDAQ&R=1&printable=1

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post the URL, this is just a guess . . .

```
Sub Test() Dim IE As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl/analystestimates" ' should work for any URL
    Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

        x = .document.body.innertext
        y = InStr(1, x, "Average Target Price:")
        Z = Mid(x, y, 6)

        Range("A1").Value = Trim(Z)

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Think that y needs to be offset by the length of the text "Average Target Price:" - `Mid(x, y + 21, 6)` - otherwise this will always grab the text "Averag"